# which is the best practice to write keys in any language?

Tags: optimization, ident

which is the best practice?:

```
if(1){
    demo();
}
```

Or

```
if(1)
{
    demo();
}
```

And parentesis:

```
if(1)
```

Or

```
if( 1 )
```

And that one way is better than another?. There are some standard about it?

Comment: This is really opinion based, and is personal preference.

Comment: the second one, providing you make space between if and parenthesis, the second one because you better can match the braces

Comment: Follow the conventions of the project (this is the *most* important for existing code), de facto language formatting rules, organizational / team guidelines, and barring thoses .. the formatting that *you* prefer and want to deal with. (And *why* is this tagged as "optimization"? I put my down-vote in for that alone.)

Comment: Anyway, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style which covers many styles found in C-like languages. I'm sure there is similar for parenthesis..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer will depend on the type of the language you are using, and the type of the program you are writing. Some will be better than others in some situations and others will worse that others in other situations. The best way really, is to use them in different programs and/or languages and learn for yourself which is the best for you. Everyone's answer have their up's and down's, but it is up to you to decide. I hope this helps you!